# Encoding of spaces in POJO parameters in Axis2

Tags: web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I have created a very simple service that just echos some text to the console. The service is just a POJO with a method echo, having a single parameter:

```
public class EchoTest
{
    public void echo(String myMessage)
    {
        System.out.println(myMessage);
    }
}
```

Ths is from the services.xml:

```
<service name="EchoTest">
    <description>Echo test</description>
    <parameter name="ServiceClass">EchoTest</parameter>

     <operation name="echo">
        <messageReceiver  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver" />
    </operation>
</service>
```

Further I use a very simple HTML form to submit the data to the service:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" target="responseFrame" action="../../services/EchoTest/echo">
        <input name="myMessage" type="text">
        <input value="Send" type="submit"/>         
    </form>
    <iframe width=500 height=500 name="responseFrame"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I have is that spaces are replaced with '+'. For example, if I type a message like this:

```
Hey you & you - # % @
```

The result is this:

```
Hey+you+&+you+-+#+%+@
```

Do I have to encode it somehow or or should it not behave like this? Or perhaps it is a setup issue? I am using Tomcat as a web container. For information, I use a servlet filter in Tomcat to e.g. filter on IP addresses, and in there I can see that the myMessage parameter looks OK, not having + signs.

Comment: The URL spec says that spaces should be encoded as `+` symbols in request parameters. Are you saying that you fetch the parameter value on the server side and it's still encoded? That doesn't seem right...

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Yes, this is the message on the server side. And another really weird thing is that if I write a + sign in the message, like test+test, the + does not get encoded in any way, the message just remains test+test. If I write test + test, it will become test+++test. Meaning that I can't even decode it properly :/

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like something is terribly wrong, here. You have this all deployed via Axis2 with no additional configuration than what is shown above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was in fact within Axis2 itself. I am not sure exactly, but the version that I was using was release 1.5.1 from October 2009. What bugs me is that I have not found any bug report on it. It could be that it was fixed quickly and that I was unfortunate.

Upgrading to a the latest version of Axis2 solved the problem.